# Decided to install ArchLinux, but faced a problem with Windows

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, boot-loader

I decided to install ArchLinux and the tutorial I found wanted to create the partitions in advance. So I made the ext4 and linux-swap partitions and saw in gParted my old friends - the Windows partitions, the one called SYSTEM and another one, which Windows creates itself, named System Reserved. So i deleted both. And now the computer doesn't know there is an OS on my computer. I receive the pxe-mof message. What should I do?

Comment: It sounds like you deleted your EFI Partition.  Google "Recreate EFI Partition"

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an OS on your computer if you didn't finish the arch install. If you were trying to dual boot you have borked it. When you deleted the windows partitions you deleted windows. You should have compressed them down and installed arch in the free space. Follow the arch beginners guide carefully and do everything it says then enjoy your new windows free life.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide

Comment: Deleting a partition in the partition table is not the same as overwriting the partition itself - it is likely still there, and the partition table may even be backed up if the disk was originally formatted with a tool that exercises more sense than does `GParted` - but to one without the skills to recreate the partition table the two things may as well be one and the same.

Comment: I didn't need Windows at all. The problem was that I deleted not the Windows drive, but the drive, Windows creates for booting the system (around 100MiB in size), which stores the bootloader. Everything is fine now, I answered my question below.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, that it all was a bootloader problem. The pxe-mof message is showing when there is no installation media on the network. Because there is no bootloader, the BIOS doesn't understand that there is an OS installed and goes through all the boot media (ordered in the F2 Setup). Usually, the "Boot from LAN" option is the last, and if there is no installation media on the network the pxe-mof message shows. I just replaced GRUB as my bootloader of choice (because I faced some obstacles configuring it) with SYSLINUX, configured it properly and now everything works perfectly. By the way, if someone experience a problem with "Invalid /dev/sda3" in SYSLINUX, that is because the default partition in syslinux's configuration is sda3. Just go to /boot/syslinux/syslinux.conf and change /dev/sda3 to whatever your boot partition is. :)

I have written this from Arch Linux with KDE installed :)